# How can I get cookie from browser in Next js (without use getServerSide or getInitialProps)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, next.js

I want to get my authToken which located in
[cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrUdc.png).

But when I tried to get it, I got undefined or something like this.
I wanted to use useContext and put _app in the context(to check if the user is authorized in child elements), but I can't get the cookie in any way.

I can get cookie in following code that located in adminPanel element, but I don't want to break the DRY principle. Maybe you can recommend me some methods to get global context for auth? (without next-auth or something like

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
if (ctx.req) {
    axios.defaults.headers.get.Cookie = ctx.req.headers.cookie
    return {
        props: {
            cookie: ctx.req.headers.cookie ? ctx.req.headers.cookie : ''
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to get at least something similar to the authorization token in _app, but nothing worked (i also tried getServerSideProps).

```
export async function getInitialProps(ctx) {
return {
    props:{
        ctx
    }
}
```

}

In this case I got ctx: undefined...

Maybe you can recommend me some methods to get global context for auth? (without next-auth or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to this question, so forgive me if I fail to answer directly, please let me know if you need further elaboration.

Firstly, there is a helper package for using cookies in next: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-cookies

Secondly, if you want to keep your `getServerSideProps` DRY, you can always make a reusable function or a HOC wrapper and load it into whichever pages need it.

Thirdly, getting the context is slightly different for _app.jsx than it is to regular pages. The page-context is wrapped in an app-context, like so:

```
import App from "next/app";

class MyApp extends App {
   //...
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appCtx) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appCtx);

  const { ctx } = appCtx;

  console.log(ctx);

  // todo: get your data from ctx here
};
```

But beware, this will kill the static optimisation for your entire site, so it's best to keep it to just each page that needs it.